# Querying SQLITE DB for Data from One Column Based On Another Column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I hope the title of this post makes sense.

The db in question has two columns that are related to my issue, a date column that follows the format xx/xx/xxxx and price a column. What I want to do is get a sum of the prices in the price column based on the month and year in which they occurred, but that data is in the other aforementioned column. Doing so will allow me to determine the total for a given month of a given year. The problem is I have no idea how to construct a query that would do what I need. I have done some reading on the web, but I'm not really sure how to go about this. Can anyone provide some advice/tips?

Thanks for your time!

Mike

I was able to find a solution using a LIKE clause:

```
SELECT sum(price) FROM purchases WHERE date LIKE '11%1234%'
```

The "11" could be any 2-digit month and the "1234" is any 4 digit year. The % sign acts as a wildcard. This query, for example, returns the sum of any prices that were from month 11 of year 1234 in the db.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) on these date values because you have stored them formatted for displaing instead of in one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

If the month and day fields always have two digits, you can use [substr](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

```
SELECT substr(MyDate, 7, 4) AS Year,
       substr(MyDate, 1, 2) AS Month,
       sum(Price)
FROM Purchases
GROUP BY Year,
         Month
```

Comment: Thanks! This works too! And it's good to know about the difference between formatting for displaying and formatting for data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

So, the goal is to get an aggregate grouping by the month?

```
select strftime('%m', mydate), sum(price)
from mytable
group by strftime('%m', mydate)
```

Look into [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Quick question, though...Is "mydate" in your example the column name?

Comment: Okay, did some reading on strftime, and I think I get your example. The catch is, I need to do the sum based on the year and the month, so wouldn't I need to include %Y somewhere in the query?